# Parameterise heterogeneous index-enabled objects

Tags: c#

Is there a way to parameterise an object based on the fact that it has an index property?

**Example**:

```
public void LoopThroughIndexer(IndexEnabledClass parameter)
{
    object value1 = parameter[1]
    object value2 = parameter[2]
    //Do stuff with value1 and value2
}
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

**EDIT 1:**
Thank you for your interest. To clear things up, by *parameterise*, I mean to make it as a argument in a method; in my example, `parameter` is of broadly defined type `IndexEnabledClass`. my question is, does something like `IndexEnabledClass` exist.

The answer seems to be no, but you can use `IEnumerable<E>`

Comment: No, I don't think so. Are you trying to make something that iterates something generically? Take an `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Comment: Could explain in greater detail, what you mean, saying _to parameterise_?

Comment: @minitech, I might give that a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is any built-in way to do that. But You could think over some variations.

Define a generic interface:

```
public interface IIndexer<T, U>
{
    T this[U index] { get; set; }
}
```

Implement it as you need (the following is only an example):

```
public class SomeClass : IIndexer<SomeClass, int>
{
    public SomeClass this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            //...
        }
        set
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `int` is the index, make a method:

```
public static void DoSomething<T>(IIndexer<T, int> obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        T o = obj[i];
        // do what you need
    }
}
```

And use the method:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
DoSomething(sc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems there is no something like `IndexEnabledClass` (in FCL). However, you can implement it by yourself.

You could use [C# Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx).

```
// Indexer declaration. 
public int this[int index]
{
    // get and set accessors
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to accept as a parameter any object that *has* an indexer.

Comment: What @minitech said is what I meant.